# Method accepting a class as its parameter

Tags: java

I have a class `FTSF`or rather I should say java enum  which implements `MEnum` interface and `SF` interface as follows :

```
public enum FTSF implements MEnum<FTSF>, SF {


private static final Map<String, FTSF> cmap = MEnum.bCMap(FTSF.class);
 .........
   so on and so forth
```

Questions :

1) Since  `FTSF` is a Java enum, that's why it can implement as many classes it want? I am slightly confused since `implement` keyword is usually used when a class implements an interface.

2) I know that one can pass class as an argument inside a method parameter,so above, when `FTSF` class is passed inside the `bCMap` method,i am trying to figure out what does gets passed as an argument inside `bCMap` method. Is it the class file that gets generated when we compile Java code?

Comment: 1) The `implements` relates to a generic interface `MEnum<T>`, not `FTSF`.

Comment: 2) " what does gets passed as an argument inside bCMap method" The instance of `Class<FTSF>` accessed via `FTSF.class`. I don't really understand what else you expect it to be. Perhaps it would be clearer if you could include the definition of `MEnum.bCMap`.

Comment: @AndyTurner  1) I have `MEnum` defined as a separate java class in the same package. The code above says that `public enum FTSF implements MEnum<FTSF> `, so  is it because `FTSF` is a Java enum, it can implement MEnum<FTSF> and SF both?

2) Can you elaborate more on  instance of `Class<FTSF>` accessed via `FTSF.class` ?

Comment: 1) It has nothing to do with `FTSF`. You can't declare that a class `implements` an enum type because enums aren't interfaces. 2) It's just a particular instance of [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). There is very little else to say about it.

Comment: @John are you saying that `MEnum` and `SF` are both classes, not interfaces?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou  `SF` is an interface and `MEnum` is also an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Enums, just like any other class, can implement as many interfaces as you like. (I got a bit confused as you asked "why it can implement as many classes as it wants". A class can only implement interfaces, not classes. It can *extend* only one class. As you clarified in a later comment, both `MEnum` and `SF` are interfaces.)

2) When you compile a Java class, called `T`, the Java compiler creates a single object which is an instance of a generic class `Class<T>`. This is a special class which holds information about the class you've just written - such as its name, and the set of fields and methods it contains. It's part of a feature called Reflection. In this statement from your question:

```
private static final Map<String, FTSF> cmap = MEnum.bCMap(FTSF.class);
```

the expression `FTSF.class` is a reference to this single instance of class `Class<FTSF>`. So the method bCMap() is being passed a reference to this object; however, given the context, the most likely reason for passing this argument to the method is not because the method wants to know about the class, but because the class object is being used as a dummy argument to tell the compiler that the generic method `bcMap` returns a `Map<String, FTSF>` (instead of, for example, a `Map<String, Object>`).

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you.

Comment: I should add that writing generic methods that take a dummy `Class<T>` argument was a common trick in Java 7 and earlier compilers. It is no longer required from Java 8 onwards, because the compiler can automatically deduce the generic type parameters based on the left-hand side of the assignment. So `bCMap()` could have been defined to take no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

1) Java classes can only `extend` one class, but they can `implement` as many as they want. It doesnt have to do with FTSF being an enum.

2) It is the Class object that represents the FTFS. You can also get it by calling `getClass()` as long as you arent in a subclass. It is useful for things like reflection. The documentation for it is here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For #1, I know that java classes can extend only one class but implement as many interfaces. Since in my case, it's not a Java class but Java enum which is implementing `MEnum<FTSF>`and `SF` could you tell me how does your answer relate to my question?

Comment: The same is true for enums as well as classes. Perhaps I am not understanding why are you confused...what are you expecting to happen or go wrong? Is there an error you were expecting to see?

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies my question. I just googled and saw that `Java enum type is a special kind of Java class` which  makes sense in terms of the usage of `implements` keyword.

Comment: Enums are a class, they extend [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html).